# BackboneJs Multiple Template rendering for a single view when edit vs list

Tags: backbone.js

I am developing my first backbone application and i have the following app.js code:

https://gist.github.com/mikedevita/f26cb481385c5574001e

and the following view templates:

```
<button id="addZone" class="btn btn-success">Add Zone</button>
<script type="text/template" id="zone-template">
    <td><a href="#zone/<%= id %>">(<%= id %>) <%= name %></a></td>
    <td><a href="#zone/edit/<%= id %>" class="edit"><i class="icon-edit" title="Edit"></i></a> | <a href="#zone/destroy/<%= id%>" class="destroy"><i class="icon-trash" title="Delete"></i></a></td>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="zoneEdit-template">
    <td>
        <form method="POST" class="form-inline" id="edit-form">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= name %>" class="input-small">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" title="Submit"><i class="icon-check"></i></input>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#zone/destroy/<%= id%>" class="destroy"><i class="icon-trash" title="Delete"></i></a></td>
</script>
```

How can i render the edit template for when editing a "zone" and fire off the list template (default) when the edit is finished.

It works great right now to render the edit template when you click the edit icon, but i cant figure out how to get it to fire the list template on change event of the model.

I have a full working setup of the app on my c9 account:
https://c9.io/gorelative/backbone-test

Comment: You should put the view code in your question instead of pointing to a whole app code.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, it turns out it was just a missing call to a function. You were declaring `this.render` in the `model.change` callback instead of properly calling the function `this.render();`

```
App.Views.Zone = Backbone.View.extend({
  //...
initialize: function(){
  this.template = _.template( $('#zone-template').html() );
  this.model.on('change', function(){ 
    this.template = _.template( $('#zone-template').html() ); 
    this.render(); /* you were not calling  */
  }, this);
  this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
},
//...
});
```